# Setting a Minimum Date for JXDatePicker in a JTable column

Tags: java, swing, jtable, swingx

How can i set a minimum date for the JXDatePicker in my JTable column.That is i need to show/enable only the date greater than current date in the JXDatePicker,date below current date should be desabled in the calender so that user can't select those dates.How to do that?Please help me.Below is my code.

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

import org.jdesktop.swingx.table.DatePickerCellEditor;


public class TableWithDate {

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableWithDate");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTable table = new JTable(new Object[][] { { "1", new Date() } },
            new Object[] { "Id", "Time" });

    TableColumn dateColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
    dateColumn.setCellEditor(new DatePickerCellEditor());

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table); 

    frame.add(scrollPane);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: The `JXDatePicker` field has `protected` access, you'll have to extend `DatePickerCellEditor` and provide that functionality...

Comment: How could i do that...please give me an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `JXDatePicker` field has `protected` access, you'll have to extend `DatePickerCellEditor` and provide that functionality...

```
public class BoundDatePickerCellEditor extends DatePickerCellEditor {

    public BoundDatePickerCellEditor() {
        super();
    }

    public BoundDatePickerCellEditor(DateFormat dateFormat) {
        super(dateFormat);
    }

    public void setLowerBound(Date date) {
        datePicker.getMonthView().setLowerBound(date);          
    }

    public void setUpperBound(Date date) {
        datePicker.getMonthView().setLowerBound(date);          
    }

}
```

**Runnable example...**

[image: Picker]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.table.DatePickerCellEditor;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                JTable table = new JTable(new Object[][]{{"1", new Date()}},
                                new Object[]{"Id", "Time"});

                TableColumn dateColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
                BoundDatePickerCellEditor picker = new BoundDatePickerCellEditor();
                picker.setLowerBound(new Date());
                dateColumn.setCellEditor(picker);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class BoundDatePickerCellEditor extends DatePickerCellEditor {

        public BoundDatePickerCellEditor() {
            super();
        }

        public BoundDatePickerCellEditor(DateFormat dateFormat) {
            super(dateFormat);
        }

        public void setLowerBound(Date date) {
            datePicker.getMonthView().setLowerBound(date);
        }

        public void setUpperBound(Date date) {
            datePicker.getMonthView().setLowerBound(date);
        }

    }
}
```

If you want to disclude today as well, you could use something like...

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
picker.setLowerBound(cal.getTime());
```

...for example

Comment: how could i access this class??

Comment: Like you do any class, `dateColumn.setCellEditor(new BoundDatePickerCellEditor());` - You might want to reconsider coding up a UI until you have these basic concepts in had, cause this is pretty much your bread and butter in GUIs

Comment: if i define this class inside my class TableWithDate it showing some errors,hence i created a this class outside my class and it doesn't disable the date less than current date

Comment: That's probably because your `createAndShowGUI` is `static` and you've defined the inner class as not `static`, personally I'd make it an external class. *"and it doesn't disable the date less than current date "* - That's probably because you haven't told it to, you need to set the `lowerBound` property accordingly...

Comment: oh yes,thats bcs of the static class issue.that's why i asked u how to access ur class.

Comment: i had set lowerbound as follows.public void setLowerBound(Date date) {
         Calendar calendar = datePicker.getMonthView().getCalendar();
         calendar.setTime(new Date());
            datePicker.getMonthView().setLowerBound(calendar.getTime());          
        }   but still can't disable the previous dates

Comment: BoundDatePickerCellEditor newBound=new BoundDatePickerCellEditor();
        Date now=new Date();
     newBound.setLowerBound(now);
        dateColumn.setCellEditor(newBound);   is that you mean?

Comment: but it doesn't not disable the click event in that unwanted date and the JTable cell receives a null value...

Comment: The don't use `DefaultTableModel`, create your own custom `TableModel` from an `AbstractTableModel` and in the `setValueAt` handle the possibility for a `null` value, basically ignoring it...the functionality you have described is, AFAIK is how the date picker works

Comment: is there any way to disable the click event in the calender if i click the JXDatePicker.that is the JXDatePicker doesn't close if i click those crossed dates.JXDatePicker close only if i click the date greater than current date.no problem for using DefaultTableModel in my code

Comment: Not unless you want to make your own `JXMonthView`

Comment: how can i do it with using JXMonthView

Comment: You need to download the source and take a look at the `BasicMonthViewUI` class.  Within in it's `MouseListener`, it is deciding what should happen.  The crappy news is, the inner class is `private`, so you can't just extend it...What you "might" be able to do is take a look at the `BasicDatePickerUI` and trace through the usable of the `commit` method, which is actually handling the closing of the popup...

Comment: Considering the knots I just tied myself into, I'm not sure it's entirely worth the effort...